# Tableau: Add possible values to a datasource field domain

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible in Tableau to add new possible values to the domain of a field in a datasource?

Context: I want to create a group from a given field in my datasource but  I don't have all possible values of it's domain in the datasource. Due to that, Tableau will set the domain of the field as a subset of the actual domain.

I'm using Tableau 10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the grouping option on a dimension, you could create a calculated field using a CASE statement that has line entries for your additional values.

Comment: That worked, but now I'm trying to add that field as a filter with a single value dropdown. This is not possible, because if I set the Filter as General -> Select from list, I won't have all possible values; if I select Custom value list, it can't be a single value dropdown. Any idea?

Comment: If I specify the Filter as General -> Use all, will it use all the domain values if the datasource is more complete?

Comment: @LuisAlves I imagine that it would, if you specify use all, and new values come into the domain; however, if you were to use custom value list and select all current values, I imagine default behavior would not automatically pick it up.  Is there a way you can mock data to try

Comment: Also, if I want to use that field as the one that specifies the color, I won't be able to specify the color for all possible values (only for the ones in the datasource)

Comment: It also prevents me from using aliases :(

Comment: That is true.  If you have the option in your datasource.  Another idea would be to append/union fake data to the source that contains your value, and then filter them out on all views.  Then at least they would be present for populating filter values in the datasource